# My Question is about changing a UIImage when a button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton, uiimage

So I am quite new to coding, learning Swift 3 on Udemy. I'm trying to test my skills by building a music app that contains 3 sound files, at the moment I am struggling to get the image of the current song that should be playing once my UIButton is pressed. I have created an array containing the image files but for some reason it only shows 2 out of the 3 images and will not go further nor will it let me loop the images, any and all suggestions are welcome.

I have tried a for-in loop which is not what I want at the moment. I am trying to get the function to update songImage to accept my array and link to the sender.tag property to cycle through the images

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

// Instance Variables
var playTheSong : AVAudioPlayer!

var imageArray = ["songImage1", "songImage2", "songImage3"]
var allSongNamesAndDescriptions = MusicClassBank()
var nextImage = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    albumArtwork.image = UIImage(named: "songImage3")

}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    updateSongImage(selectedImageFile: imageArray[sender.tag - 1])

    nextImage = nextImage + 1
}

@IBOutlet weak var albumArtwork: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var nameOfSong: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var songDescription: UILabel!

// Cycle through images upon button being pressed.

func updateSongImage(selectedImageFile : String) {

    if nextImage <= 3 {
    albumArtwork.image = UIImage(named: selectedImageFile)
    }
    else {
        nextImage = 0
    }

}
```

Right now the code is showing just the image displayed upon view load and the next image in the array. I cannot get it to go through the entire array and keep going when the button is pressed.

Comment: This looks "right" in the sense that the functionality works but the code could be improved -- anywho -- the only problem I could see is possibly in how you set your `sender.tag` variables for each button. This might be returning a number you might not think. `print(sender.tag-1)` and see what prints out to determine if you are actually obtaining the correct number.

Comment: if your array has only three images, and you start nextImage from 0, the  if condition shud be if nextImage <= 2

Comment: I only have one button, called buttonPressed - the title is next song i want to be able to click it to change the image of the song currently being played, at the moment when i print the sender.tag statement it prints either 0 or 1 depending if i have it set as sender.tag - 1 or not. just not showing the third picture in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the "next" UIButton `sender.tag` as a parameter to change the image, but that tag never changes. So:

- In your `viewDidLoad()` method, you show the third image
- When you press the "next" button, you update the image to 1 (probably the `sender.tag` is 1)
- Pressing the button again don't update the image

You can try something like this:

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    //Set the first image
    updateSongImage(selectedImageFile : imageArray[0])
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //If nextImage is less than imageArray.count - 1 (because arrays start with 0), add one to nextImage. Else, nextImage return to zero
    nextImage = nextImage < imageArray.count - 1 ? nextImage + 1 : 0
    updateSongImage(selectedImageFile: imageArray[nextImage])
}

func updateSongImage(selectedImageFile : String) {
    //Here we only need to update the image, because the if is outside
    albumArtwork.image = UIImage(named: selectedImageFile)
}
```

Comment: This is what I have done so far to combat the problem : I have made three buttons with their own sender.tag numbers - now the application works absolutely fine, however in order to reach this point I have had to make 3 separate buttons and linked the code to the sender.tag number for each button, I tried your method (might be a bit to advanced for me at the moment) - anyway I can achieve this result with just 1 button?

Comment: Hello. Yes, I thought you only had one “next” button, and that button was passing the song to the next, and if there was no more songs it would go back to the first one. This code does this.